Multiple voltage source problem from Boylestead
Good day
I'm doing this problem from a textbook and I cannot understand how they got the answer. So I have to determine the voltages Va, Vb and Vab. There is a process to do this that I don't think I know about. I simply said that Vb is 6v and then added 21v onto that to say that Va is 27v but this doesn't agree with the answer in the book. It agrees that Vb is 6v but says that Va is 13v and Vab is 7v. So that leaves me in a quandary about what is going on over the 21v source. It seems that is only 7v across it and not 21. Can someone explain what I'm missing here

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

As shown, you are correct with the voltages. I suspect you have misstated or misunderstood the question.

Thank you @KevinWhite

Replace V3 with - 8V voltage source and you will get the book's answer.

The values for Va & Vb you stated are correct for the diagram you drew.  If the book does not agree then either the book is incorrect, or you have misstated the question.
Perhaps V2 is not a voltage source, but a volt meter?  In that case, Va is 13V, Vb is 6V, so Vab = 7V, which seems to agree with the answer is the book.
Or perhaps V2 was intended to be a resistor of 21 ohms?  In that case the voltages are the same, only the current will be different compared to the case where V2 is a voltmeter.

I think you are right in the answer at the back of the book being incorrect. I checked the diagram and i have drawn it correct. The question simply states: "Determine the voltages Va, Vb and Vab for the networks in Fig. 118." I got the first two right and this was the third and final one which I found trouble on. Thanks @FabioBarone

Please provide the details of the text book.  The publisher may have a website where corrections are listed.

Boylestad, Introductory Circuit Analysis, 11ed. Q. 35, page 181. @FabioBarone

This book is a very good book. I found a link to the book in digital form, not sure if I can put link in here, but I googled "boylestad introductory circuit analysis 11th edition errata" - @FabioBarone
